# System of differential equations with three unknown functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So I have this system of differential equations, which I've been trying to solve for quite a while.
$$c_1' = a_2c_3-a_3c_2+b_1\\
c_2'=a_3c_1-a_1c_3+b_2\\
c_3'=\lambda(a_1c_2-a_2c_1)+b_3$$
where $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2 \text{ and } c_3$ are functions of $t; \lambda,  a_3\text{ and } b_3$ are constants. Given that $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ are known functions, how do I solve for $c_1, c_2 \text{ and } c_3$?

My main goal is to get a differential equation with only one unknown function.
I have tried solving them by using matrices and eigenvectors but it doesn't work.
I tried solving for one function and substituting back and again it doesn't work.
The problem seems to be that $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are missing in $c_1', c_2', c_3'$ equations respectively.

Comment: Why an approach via matrices doesn't work? It have to be the most definitive way.

Comment: I tied again. It worksed